# drupal 7, pre populate field values from previous data

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-forms

My situation is, when I click to add new content of lets say type "project", I want the fields be prepopulated with last entered values.. Since there is more then 40 fields, i don't want to fill every field individually..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer may not be so simple. The best way i can think of is to create a custom module, hook_form_alter the node-edit form and change the #default_value of the form fields/elements you care about.

So in the defualt_value attribute of this you could implement a custom function that brings the data you need or hardcode the values

Answer (score -1):

use devel module in drupal it creates content manually for specific content type i think it useful 4 u

Comment: I dont think this is the case here, the question is not about content generation , is about default values in the node-edit form

Comment: but for create custom module it create large content and it contain 40 or more filed so write custom module it is so tough